# Retry Single Iteration in For Loop (Python)

Tags: python, pandas, loops, for-loop, yahoo-api

Python novice here (sorry if this is a dumb question)! I'm currently using a for loop to download and manipulate data. Unfortunately, I occasionally run into brief network issues that cause portions of the loop to fail.

Originally, I was doing something like this:

```
# Import Modules
import fix_yahoo_finance as yf
import pandas as pd
from stockstats import StockDataFrame as sdf

# Stock Tickers to Gather Data For - in my full code I have thousands of tickers
Ticker = ['MSFT','SPY','GOOG']

# Data Start and End Data
Data_Start_Date = '2017-03-01'
Data_End_Date = '2017-06-01'

# Create Data List to Append
DataList = pd.DataFrame([])

# Initialize Loop
for i in Ticker:
    # Download Data
    data = yf.download(i, Data_Start_Date, Data_End_Date)
    # Create StockDataFrame
    stock_df = sdf.retype(data)
    # Calculate RSI
    data['rsi'] = stock_df['rsi_14']
    DataList.append(pd.DataFrame(data))

DataList.to_csv('DataList.csv',header=True,index=True)
```

With that basic layout, whenever I had a network error, it caused the entire program to halt and spit out an error.

I did some research and tried modifying the 'for loop' to following:

```
for i in Ticker:
  try:
    # Download Data
    data = yf.download(i, Data_Start_Date, Data_End_Date)
    # Create StockDataFrame
    stock_df = sdf.retype(data)
    # Calculate RSI
    data['rsi'] = stock_df['rsi_14']
    DataList.append(pd.DataFrame(data))
  except:
    continue
```

With this, the code always ran without issue, but whenever I encountered a network error, it skipped all the tickers it was on (failed to download their data).

I want this to download the data for each ticker once. If it fails, I want it to try again until it succeeds once and then move on to the next ticker. I tried using `while True` and variations of it, but it caused the loop to download the same ticker multiple times!

Any help or advice is greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: show you while loop attempt please

Answer (score 2):

If you can *continue* after you've hit a glitch (some protocols support it), then you're better off not using this exact approach. But for a slightly brute-force method:

```
for i in Ticker:
  incomplete = True
  tries = 10
  while incomplete and tries > 0:
    try:
      # Download Data
      data = yf.download(i, Data_Start_Date, Data_End_Date)
      incomplete = False
    except:
      tries -= 1
  # Create StockDataFrame
  if incomplete:
    print("Oops, it is really failing a lot, skipping: %r" % (i,))
    continue # not technically needed, but in case you opt to add
             # anything afterward ...
  else:
    stock_df = sdf.retype(data)
    # Calculate RSI
    data['rsi'] = stock_df['rsi_14']
    DataList.append(pd.DataFrame(data))
```

This is slighly different that Prune's in that it stops after 10 attempts ... if it fails that many times, that indicates you may want to divert some energy into fixing a different problem such as network connectivity.

If it gets to that point, it will continue in the list of `Ticker`s, so perhaps you can get most of what you need.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a wrapper loop to continue until you get a good result.

```
for i in Ticker:
  fail = True

  while fail:     # Keep trying until it works
    try:
      # Download Data
      data = yf.download(i, Data_Start_Date, Data_End_Date)
      # Create StockDataFrame
      stock_df = sdf.retype(data)
      # Calculate RSI
      data['rsi'] = stock_df['rsi_14']
      DataList.append(pd.DataFrame(data))
    except:
      continue
    else:
      fail = False
```

Comment: When is `fail` anything other than `False`? (I think your first assignment should be `fail=True` in line 2.)

Comment: isn't a simple `while True` + `break` at the and of the `try` block doing exactly that (instead of manually dealing with a `fail` bool)?

Comment: Good point, @Julien, though tracking *something* might be beneficial, such as including a fail-limit (as I did in my answer). Omitting that single `bool`, however, requires some other form of determining if the data is complete without explicitly accessing `data` (unless it was previously set to something like `None`).

Comment: @`both-of-you`: good points.  I coded this as a generic version, easy to alter to invert the logic, or to add a counter for attempts.

Comment: I ended up going with r2evans's approach. It works perfectly! Thanks again for the help!